# setcontentview within onpostExecution

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-activity, task, setcontentview

Hi I am working with android.How can I use setContentview within Onpostexecution of asynchronous task ??I used the code

```
  if (getIntent().hasExtra("key")) {

                                if(key.compareTo(App_id)==0)
                                  {
                                    setContentView(R.layout.home); 
                                  }

                              }
                              else {

                                     finish();
                                   }
```

But it force closed and shows the error nullpointer exception. How Can I use setcontentview within onpost execute??

here is my logcat output

```
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.meetap.AdHome}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.example.meetap.AdHome.onCreate(AdHome.java:374)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
03-20 13:47:30.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     ... 11 more
```

Edit:

I have `NullPointerException` at

```
Button close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.close); 
close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{ 
public void onClick(View v) 
{
 finish(); 
} 
});
```

Comment: is Asynctask an inner class of Activity?

Comment: yaa I used asynchronous task as inner class

Comment: post the stacktrace also

Comment: post AddHome code and indicate line  374

Comment: check my new edit to see my log cat

Comment: Button close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
   close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
   
    public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
     
    }
   });

Comment: check that your xml layout contains a button with id 'R.id.close'

Answer (score 0):

```
Button close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.close); 
close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{ 
public void onClick(View v) 
{
 finish(); 
} 
});
```

If you say NPE in the above `close` button is null. You need to have  `setContentView(R.layout.home);` before button is initialized and need to make sure that `home.xml` has a button with id close.

Edit:

> It is defined in another xml

You need to inflate the custom layout like

```
View view = infalter.inflate(R.layout.customlayout,null);
Button close=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.close);
```

Comment: I used it as custom title bar

Comment: It is defined in another xml

Comment: @prince does not matter. Then you need to inflate the custom layout and initialize it using the custom view object

Comment: I used as u said .I tried to setcontentview within poast execute method .but action of onclick button is in the activity. so is run before post execute right???

Comment: you are confusing me. I can't understand your comments. Pls be clear.

Comment: instead of it I used     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.close);      for popupview

Comment: I used setContentview in inner class and customview button action in  activity. So which will execute first ??

Comment: asynctask is asynchronous. Its depends on the sequence of statements that you have. You certainly need to read about asynctask in the docs. You have no idea about it i guess

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your getIntent()!= null. have you check you 'key' != null

Comment: that i had with hasextra

Comment: when you get exception, at the time of layout initialization or on button click ?

Comment: then the possibility is may be your layout doesn't contains button with id 'R.id.close', and if does check that you initialize it before setting onClickListener.